# ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables in merge query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I really don't understand why I am getting error with the below query as `ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables` as i have provided `distinct` clause in my `merge` query and also BB_TST_HISTORY has appropriate unique constraint.

```
merge into bb_tst_history h
using (select distinct r.ausuebungsbezeichnung
       from   bb_tst_rollup r
       join   ( select root, boerse, security_typ
                from   bb_export_filter
                minus
                select root, boerse, security_typ
                from   bb_tst_exception
              ) e
              on   r.root = e.root
              and  r.security_typ = e.security_typ
              and  r.boerse = e.boerse
      ) s
on (s.root = h.root and s.security_typ = h.security_typ and s.boerse = h.boerse)
when matched then
    update set h.ausuebungsbezeichnung = s.ausuebungsbezeichnung
when not matched then
    insert values (s.ausuebungsbezeichnung);
```

Comment: sorry i have edited my query...actually i am using lot of columns in select query and deleted the other part of the coulmns..so its typo

Comment: The combination of `s.root`, `s.security_typ` and `s.boerse` needs to be unique. (`s` only returns `ausuebungsbezeichnung` though so it's not quite clear what is going on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have single record for matching criteria in the `USING` clause.

so you can use the `GROUP BY` and `MAX` in `USING` clause as follows:

```
MERGE INTO BB_TST_HISTORY H
USING (
          SELECT MAX(R.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG) AS AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG, 
                 R.ROOT, R.SECURITY_TYP, R.BOERSE
            FROM BB_TST_ROLLUP R
            JOIN (
              SELECT ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP
                FROM BB_EXPORT_FILTER
              MINUS
              SELECT ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP
                FROM BB_TST_EXCEPTION
          ) E
          ON R.ROOT = E.ROOT
             AND R.SECURITY_TYP = E.SECURITY_TYP
             AND R.BOERSE = E.BOERSE
         GROUP BY R.ROOT, R.SECURITY_TYP, R.BOERSE
      ) S ON ( S.ROOT = H.ROOT
   AND S.SECURITY_TYP = H.SECURITY_TYP AND S.BOERSE = H.BOERSE )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET H.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG = S.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT VALUES ( S.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG );
```

Comment: i ran the select query suggested by below answer and it did not return any rows so it means the query doesnt produce multiple duplicated rows...

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you are getting more than one row in your source for the joining columns. Best way to approach this issue is, identifying those records which are causing issue. Below SQL can give you those records -

```
select root, security_typ, boerse, count(1) from
(select distinct r.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG from BB_TST_ROLLUP r,      
          (select ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP from BB_EXPORT_FILTER minus 
select ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP from BB_TST_EXCEPTION)) 
group by root, security_typ, boerse having count(1) > 1;
```

You need to update additional join condition in 'ON' clause to fix this issue.

Updated Merge Statement -

```
merge into BB_TST_HISTORY h   using  
    (    select ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP, AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG from (select distinct r.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG from BB_TST_ROLLUP r       
        join     
          (select ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP from BB_EXPORT_FILTER minus 
select ROOT, BOERSE, SECURITY_TYP from BB_TST_EXCEPTION))) e       
        on      r.root=e.root and r.security_typ=e.security_typ and r.boerse=e.boerse  ) s 
on (s.root=h.root and s.security_typ=h.security_typ and s.boerse=h.boerse) 
        when matched then   update set h.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG = s.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG
        when not matched then   insert values (s.AUSUEBUNGSBEZEICHNUNG);
```

Comment: the query throws an error as missing keyword near group by clause...

Comment: thank you. There was a missing ')' in SQL. I corrected it. I have taken the source SQL as it is from the question. I notice it produces a cartesian as the join condition is missing in this SQL.

Comment: it still throws same error now where you have added extra ))

Comment: yes its [Code: 905, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00905: missing keyword

Comment: can you try the update SQL now? Post the error message if error still persists.

Comment: well the query runs and it did not return any rows , it means it doesnt have duplicate values

Comment: hmm. you can have a look on solution suggested by @Tejash or you can try updated merge statement provided by me in my answer.